# 0x bsc api returning the wrong path for Pancakeswap router v2

Tags: pancakeswap, 0x

I query the api for bsc

https://bsc.api.0x.org/swap/v1/quote?buyToken=0x368ce786ea190f32439074e8d22e12ecb718b44c&sellToken=0xe9e7cea3dedca5984780bafc599bd69add087d56&sellAmount=1000000000000000000

I am looking for pancakeswap so I filter for source = "PancakeSwap_V2", I get a path which is impossible

My result path = dai -> busd -> epik

Sometimes I get path: peggedEth->epik->busd and something similar but never the real path, when the path should be busd -> wbnb -> epik

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

By looking for PancakeSwap do you mean you want your order to be exclusively routed through PancakeSwap?

Currently we don't have a way to filter by `includedSources` except in the case of RFQ liquidity. However, the above request at the current time of writing routes through MultiHop, so if you include the param `excludedSources=MultiHop` it will exclude this source and give you the next best possible pricing (exclusively via PancakeSwap V2 at the time of writing).